# Windows 10: Set any browser as default when it does not show up in Settings?

Tags: windows-10, browser, default-settings

In windows 10, programs cannot make themselves set as default. The only thing they can do is open the Windows Settings page (Settings\System\Default Apps, and allow you to change the Web browser manually.

However, it can happen that the web browser you are using is not listed there.

Alternative solution would be to go to the classic *Control Panel*, *Default Programs*, *Set your default programs*.

But, what if your browser is not listed there either?

For me, this is the case with Vivaldi after I installed Firefox and set it as default a while ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is software available that would fix the issue, but here's a manual routine you can do that will also work.

**This technique is not limited to making your web browser default, but can be used for everything in the Settings page and more, as long as you know at least one file extension your program can open.**

## 1. Show extensions for all filetypes

It is important that extensions are shown for all filetypes. To enable this, open a file explorer window, go to the tab *View*, and at the right check `[v] File name extensions`

## 2. Create a temporary file with .htm extension

Now, if you haven't needed to do step 1 or already closed the file explorer, open a file explorer. Navigate to any folder where you have write permissions. You can actually also use your desktop if you find that easier.

Right click, choose *New* > *Text file* to create an empty textfile.

Rename the file to `temp.htm` The temp part is not so much important, but make sure the file ends with `.htm`. Click <kbd>Yes</kbd> on the question if you are sure to change the filetype.

## 3. Create a new file association for .htm files

Right click your .htm file and go to *Open With* > *Choose another app*

NOTE: It may very well be that your app is listed in this list. If so, still choose *Choose another app*.

In the next window, at the bottom, there's a checkbox labelled `[v] Always use this app to open .htm files.`. Make sure its checked.

If your program is at the top list, select it there. If not, scroll to the bottom where it says `Choose an app from your pc`. This opens a file open dialog, allowing you to browse to the program on your harddrive.

When you press OK, all .htm files are now opened by your browser of choice, but this does not set your browser as default.

## 4. Set your browser as default

Step 3 did not just assign your browser to open .htm files, but it fixed the registry item, causing your browser to be selectable in the Settings screen *Set default app*. If you now go to *Start > Settings > System > Default Apps*, you will be able to select your browser as default web browser.

Answer (score 1):

None of the above and no other tips worked.

All you need to do is open a command window (cmd) and paste in:

```
"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\uninstall\helper.exe" /SetAsDefaultAppGlobal
```

Comment: This fixed it for me when Firefox wasn't showing in the list of possible default browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use the Settings page.  You can do it on the command line with [`ftype`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ftype).

`ftype htmlfile="%ProgramFiles%\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" "%1"`