# HOW TO change default browser of MS Word when I ctrl-click a hyperlink

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

When I ctrl-click a hyperlink in a Word document on Windwos10, it opens Edge.
I want it to open IE11.

Comment: Set the default browser to IE11 in that case.

Comment: As per @LPChip stated in this answer.... [***"If you now go to Start > Settings > System > Default Apps, you will be able to select your browser as default web browser"***](https://superuser.com/questions/1125989/windows-10-set-any-browser-as-default-when-it-does-not-show-up-in-settings/1125990#1125990) in the **Set your browser as default** section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem and just found an [answer](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/unable-open-a-link-to-a-website-in-word-2013/0bf3fc6c-0f32-4d03-9ee7-34d1553d349e?auth=1) that worked for me which I will recreate here so we don't lose it. Try this but substitute IE11 for Edge.

In my case Chrome as already my default browser, yet following these directions I still had the option to choose 'Chrome' versus "use my current web browser" (apparently 'my current web browser' != my default web browser. Interesting choice of words there.)

You may have to hunt around for where you set the 'default programs' in Windows 10, these instructions were for Windows 7.

> Click Start, select Default Programs
>
> Click Set program access and computer defaults
>
> Click Custom, and select Google Chrome
>
> Click OK
>
> Then, follow these steps:
>
> Click Set your default programs
>
> Select Google Chrome from the list
>
> Click Set this program as default
>
> Click OK

Credit to Ramesh Srinivasan (Marking community wiki, as this was NOT my answer but it solved my problem.)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Microsoft word so here is my solution,
This is the solutions on windows 10.

1. Press windows key
2. Search up default app settings and click
3. once settings is open scroll all the way down till you see your current web browser chosen (in my case it was windows explorer)
4. click on the setting and change to your preferred browser
5. Done! have fun

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10:

1. Open (setting)
2. Go to (Default apps)
3. Navigate to see (Web browser)
4. Press on the current browser appeared (for example Microsoft Edge)
5. From the pop up window select what you need (Chrome or Firefox)